# asp.net core facebook and google crawler login required pages

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core, google-crawlers

asp.net core 1.1 site I'm working on has a blog section we just built that is for members only. Also for the most recent 5 blogs also have a short message that is publicly accessible on the home page and the monthly newsletter email.

We want to be able to share the links on social media for the full blog page but require login on clicking. 
Tweeter is easy on sharing.
But the crawlers for google and facebook goes to login page.
We don't want the crawling the full page since its members only. 
I did find the crawler page for facebook and google, 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en

but wouldn't this cache the full body?
Am I miss informed on crawlers.

Comment: _“but wouldn't this cache the full body?”_ - it caches whatever your system returns ... So setting it up to present the content you want it to in those cases, is your job. The Facebook scraper can be recognized by its User-Agent, pretty sure for Google there’s something similar.

Comment: Hmmm so only let the short version to be seen to the crawler.